# Why should I use jwt in Refresh Token?

Tags: authentication, account-security, jwt

I use Refresh Token to handling expired Access Token, and in log out, I can remove Refresh Token from the database. Refresh Token must never expire (not sure) because the user can check "remember me".

So why should I use `jwt` in Refresh Token? Can it be just a random hash string? And should it have expiration time?

Answer (score 2):

> Can it be just a random hash string?

Yes, it can be any random string. You just have to ensure that it cannot be randomly generated or guessed.

> So why should I use jwt in Refresh Token?

**jwt** has it's own pros and cons.
The main advantage being it's stateless; And you **don't need any storage**.
However, the downside is the **security depends on just one key**. If it's compromised, the whole system is compromised.

It depends on your architecture and use-case. Both jwt and random hash string are already used successfully in many production application. Choose as per your need and resources.

> And should it have expiration time?

Seems you're considering to use it. :)
Since, it's used to get a new access token in case it is expired, *refresh_token* must have long expiry time.
With above, there is concern for abuse of the refresh_token.
To mitigate it, we can take some measures. Let's take a look at the OAuth 2.0 specification. [OAuth RFC-6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.4)

> the authorization server could employ refresh token
> rotation in which a new refresh token is issued with every access
> token refresh response.  The previous refresh token is invalidated
> but retained by the authorization server.  If a refresh token is
> compromised and subsequently used by both the attacker and the
> legitimate client, one of them will present an invalidated refresh
> token, which will inform the authorization server of the breach.

Would love to know whether you used **jwt** for your purpose.
(*Do write an answer/comment here in future*)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get some good ideas, but still, there are some ambiguous parts. First of all, you say: `And you don't need any storage.` This is about the Access Token, not the Refresh Token. Because I must invalidate Refresh Token in the logout functionality, so I must save it in db. And about your reference from OAuth, would you please give me more information in the form of an example?